# Problem with dividing timeline fullcalendar in equal parts (custom timeline view)

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am trying to make a fullcalendar component which can divide a day in equal parts.
This is working for certain amounts (10, 20, ...)

But when working with a uneven amount (like 15). This does not work.

I made a code pen of a simplified version of the problem:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'today prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineTenDay,resourceTimelineMonth,resourceTimelineYear'
    },
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
    scrollTime: '08:00',
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    views: {
      resourceTimelineDay: {
          duration: { days: 21 }, // Or whatever value you want.
         slotDuration: "3:00:00",
         slotLabelInterval: "21:00:00",
         slotMaxTime: "24:00:00",
         slotWidth: "8",
         minTime: '00:00',
         maxTime: "24:00:00",
      },
      resourceTimelineTenDay: {
        type: 'resourceTimeline',
        duration: { days: 10 },
        buttonText: '10 days'
      }
    },
    editable: true,
    resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Rooms',
    resources: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-resources.json?with-nesting&with-colors',
    events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json?single-day&for-resource-timeline'
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.5.1/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.5.1/main.min.js"></script>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/developmenteye-t/pen/ExNzBGz?editors=001)

The problem with the uneven amounts we cannot reach exactly 24:00:00, this gives a problem in the visualation.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

###EDIT### extra info:

When running my code I get following results:
divided in 30 parts (which mean 48 minutes) (and 48 minutes * 30 = 24:00:00)
[image]

divided in 21 parts (which means 1 hour and 8 minutes) (1:08 * 21 = 23:48:00)
[image]

I tried using MaxTime to limit to 23:48:00, but this does not work as expected.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you're talking about the `slotLabelInterval` value (it wasn't 100% clear)? It's just a fact of maths...what did you expect to happen? `24 / 21 = 1.143`. What kind of solution would you find acceptable? You haven't really said how you would want the calendar to behave instead.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I was looking for a solution that the calendar would be less than 24 hours. But the lay-out always messes up. (see extra screenshots about the problem in my edited post)

Comment: I see. No it doesn't work like that, it treats the whole period in the layout as a continuous series of time. The only way to do anything like you're describing would be to only ever use the `day` views - e.g. like this: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/GRNbobB?editors=001 where only one day is ever shown at once

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer again. I am trying to find an other solution (I would divide the calendar always per 6 minutes and limit the shown hours. But I think I am stuck on some certain limits: https://codepen.io/developmenteye-t/pen/bGBPeGp?editors=0010 . Same settings (only difference is daycount (first one is 4 days, second one is 5 days). Would you know any alternatives to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you saying you want both of those views to be identical, apart from the extra day? I think 6-minute slots are probably a bit unrealistic to fit into the space. Try higher values and see if it works better. (I suspect that in the 5-day version the calendar has decided it can't fix the required number of vertical lines visually in the space available and has decided to reduce the number of visible lines accordingly, using the slotLabelInterval value instead.)

Comment: I am trying to find a solution so in a way I can choose how many parts there are shown. I first tried by dividing 24 hour (as mentioned above). The second idea I had was to show parts of 6 minutes and with MaxTime I could set it to 1 hour (to get 10 parts), or set it to 2 hours (to get 20 parts) and so on. Now I tried using parts of 20 minutes (which means I can choose between 1 - 72 parts). https://codepen.io/developmenteye-t/pen/bGBPeGp?editors=0010